# converting a php array into a database schema

Tags: php, database, database-design

Currently I am storing adjacencies in a php file in an array. Here's a sample of it:

```
$my_neighbor_lists = array(
1=> array(3351=> array (2, 3, 5 , 6, 10)),
2=> array(3264=> array (322, 12, 54 , 6, 10), 3471=>array (122, 233, 35 , 476, 210)),
3=> array(3309=> array (52, 32, 54 , 36, 210), 3469=>array (152, 32, 15 , 836, 10)),
etc
```

I would like to basically migrate this into a db. Any suggestions on how many table I should have? I am looking at three tables here.

Comment: What do the numbers mean? Are they ids?

Comment: which number are you referring to? the inner arrays is time intervals/costs, so (2, 3, 5, 6, 10) means at time interval 0 cost is 2, time interval 15 cost is 3 (it's divided per 15 minutes), and so on The 1=> array (3351 => ........ means that there exists a path from node 1 to 3351

Comment: You'll have to update your question with more detail regarding the background of your problem and a clear description of your array.

Answer (score 0):

two tables:

```
 1. vertices (id)
 2. edgecost (idfrom, idto, time, cost)
```

Comment: then there will be repetitions if I'd do it like this, for every idfrom - idto there is always 15 cost associated with it

Comment: I know that the idfrom-idto-time is unique, but there will be multiple repetition of idfrom-idto

Comment: so what? that's what your data structure represent - multiedged graph. if you'd store it like I said, you'd be able to select vertice-edge-weight conditions directly in SQL. e.g.  `SELECT b.id, ec.cost FROM vertices a LEFT JOIN vertices b LEFT JOIN edgecost ec ON ec.idfrom=a.id AND ec.idto=b.id WHERE a.id=[startvertice] AND ec.time<[mintime]` ORDER BY ec.cost ASC - to find all vertices adjacent to [startvertice] reachable for less then [mintime]. May be if you provide more details for your task, e.g. what are typical queries you do with that structure we could lay out better suited scheme.